# how to concatenate fields in one field while url hacking

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlhacking

I want to concatenate 3 fields and show in description field of case. I am following below approach but its not working :

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="myCtrl"
    id="createContact" action="{!nullValue(redir.url, urlFor($Action.Case.CloneChild, Case.Id, [isdtp='vw'], true)+ 
    '&cloneli=1&RecordType=' + RecordTypeId + 
    '&CF00N0k000000Gst9=' +case1.CaseNumber+ 
    '&CF00N0k000000Gst9_lkid=' +case1.Id +
    '&CF00N0k000000Gsrz=' +case1.Business_Unit__c +
    '&Description=' + case1.description + ' detail1: ' + case1.detail1 + ' detail2: ' + case1.detail2 + ' detail3: ' + case1.detail3)}">
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you should replace the "description" key with the one in the case record. I checked that it would be "cas15" instead of description so basically your url should be something like below :
Use %0A to put a break

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="myCtrl"
    id="createContact" action="{!nullValue(redir.url, urlFor($Action.Case.CloneChild, Case.Id, [isdtp='vw'], true)+ 
    '&cloneli=1&RecordType=' + RecordTypeId + 
    '&CF00N0k000000Gst9=' +case1.CaseNumber+ 
    '&CF00N0k000000Gst9_lkid=' +case1.Id +
    '&CF00N0k000000Gsrz=' +case1.Business_Unit__c +
    '&cas15=' + case1.description + '%0Adetail1: ' + case1.detail1 + '%0A detail2: ' + case1.detail2 + '%0Adetail3: ' + case1.detail3)}">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanks a ton it worked perfectly. can you tell me how can I give next line or escape sequence as separation in 3 fields?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Use %0A to put  a break.